# Fade in and Fade out with display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <style> 
        #myDIV {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            display: none;
        }

        #second {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: lightblue;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>  
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="menu" class="menu">
        <ul class="headlines">
            <li id="item1"onclick="checklist(this)"><button onclick="myFunction()">Home</button></li>
            <li id="item2"><button onclick="myFunction2()">About </button></li>
            <li id="item3">Contact us     </li>
            <li id="item4">asda     </li>
            <li id="item5">dfgdfgd</li>
            <li id="item6">sdfghs    </li>
            <li id="item7">sghsfhs    </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="myDIV">
             <img src="j.png">
        </div>
        <div id="second">
             This is my DIV2 element.
        </div>
        <script>
           function myFunction() {
                document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("second").style.display = "none";
           }
       </script>

       <script>
           function myFunction2() {
               document.getElementById("second").style.display ="block";
               document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
           }
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

The two divisions are alternating in the same place. How can i make this alteration based on fade in and fade out. as in appear(fade in) and disappear (fade out) with a delay. And is the method applicable for all the elements of the menu? Thank you

Comment: Could you add _[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/)_?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ct7c5a3b/

Comment: You guys don't need a fiddle for this! *Seriously!*

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `myFunction()` like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    $("#myDIV").fadeIn();
    $("#second").fadeOut();
}

function myFunction2() {
    $("#second").fadeIn();
    $("#myDIV").fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: ok but is this applicable to be done on all the elements of the above menu? and how can i delay the fade in and fade out factors?

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {
    $("#second").fadeOut(300, function(){
        $("#myDIV").fadeIn(300);
    });
}

function myFunction2() {
   $("#myDIV").fadeOut(300, function(){
        $("#second").fadeIn(300);
    });
}
```

try this, this will delay upto 300ms and wait for until fadeout, and it will began to fadein for 300ms

Comment: ok i'm with you on this, however can this method be done on all the elements of the above menu? and how can i delay the fade in and fade out factors?

Comment: this how needs to do, can u mention the fadein fadeout elements

Comment: @randy u want to do for menu item1, item2, item3 right

Comment: item1 item1 3 4 5 6 7